# Type cast an ActiveRecord model virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with some attributes and a virtual attribute.
This virtual attribute is used to make a checkbox in the creation form.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :foo
  attr_accessible :foo
end
```

Since the field is a checkbox in the form, the `foo` attribute will receive `'0'` or `'1'` as value. I would like it to be a boolean because of the following code:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :foo
  attr_accessible :foo

  before_validation :set_default_bar

  private

  def set_default_bar
    self.bar = 'Hello' if foo
  end
end
```

The problem here is that the condition will be true even when `foo` is `'0'`. I would like to use the ActiveRecord type casting mechanism but the only I found to do it is the following:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :foo
  attr_accessible :foo

  before_validation :set_default_bar

  def foo=(value)
    @foo = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
  end


  private

  def set_default_bar
    self.bar = 'Hello' if foo
  end
end
```

But I feel dirty doing it that way. Is there a better alternative without re-writing the conversion method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your solution from the original post looks like the best solution to me.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :foo
  def foo=(value)
    @foo = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.value_to_boolean(value)
  end
end
```

If you wanted to clean things up a bit, you could always create a helper method that defines your `foo=` writer method for you using `value_to_boolean`.

I would probably create a module with a method called `bool_attr_accessor` so you could simplify your model to look like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  bool_attr_accessor :foo
end
```

It seems like ActiveModel ought provide something like this for us, so that virtual attributes act more like "real" (ActiveRecord-persisted) attributes. This type cast is essential whenever you have a boolean virtual attribute that gets submitted from a form.

Maybe we should submit a patch to Rails...

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5 you can use `attribute` method. This method defines an attribute with a type on this model. It will override the type of existing attributes if needed.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :foo, :boolean
end
```

*Caution: there is incorrect behaviour of this `attribute` feature in rails 5.0.0 on models loaded from the db. Therefore use rails 5.0.1 or higher.*

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`validates_acceptance_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_acceptance_of) code (click **Show source**).
They implemented it with comparing to "0".

I'm using it in registrations forms in this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service
  attr_accessible :terms_of_service
end
```

---

If you really want cast from string etc you can use this:

```
def foo=(value)
  self.foo=(value == true || value==1 || value =~ (/(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)) ? true:false
end
```

Or add typecast method for `String` class and use it in model:

```
class String
 def to_bool
   return true if self == true || self =~ (/(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)
   return false if self == false || self.blank? || self =~ (/(false|f|no|n|0)$/i)
   raise ArgumentError.new("invalid value for Boolean: \"#{self}\"")
 end
end
```

Comment: Yeah maybe, but I find this way of doing it a bit dirty. I'd prefer to use a real boolean. What would happen if in some other part part of the code I write `Thing.new(foo: true)` ?

Comment: i found the String#to_bool to be clean and helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't do this :

```
def foo=(value)
  @foo = value
  @bar = 'Hello' if value == "1"
end
```

Comment: Because values could be change to `'true'` and `'false'` and it still should work. Rails does it ok but in the wrong place IMHO.

Comment: About setting @bar in `foo=` I think it's not the place to do it, single responsibility principle and all. And, in my real use-case, it make sense to place it in a before_validation ;)

Comment: You're right. You have this solution : https://gist.github.com/2000623 but I don't think it's a better solution. It's basicly the same thing than rails do. See the source : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb

Comment: Yeah I found this gist too but I didn't want to recreate the wheel :/

Comment: I think there is no better solution. If it's in Rails code, it's probably the better way...

Comment: That's why I did it this way. But I think Rails would benefit from extracting this behavior so that it's usable for a non column field.

Comment: I know, but it takes time that I don't have right now :( But if someday I can, I will ;)